# LIKE contains %

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have record in table like 'abc 100% text'.

I want to search all the records that contain 100%.

What will be `LIKE` query?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where ColName LIKE '100%%'
```

above query returns wrong results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where ColName LIKE '%100[%]%'
```

Have a look at [Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%[%]%'
```

or

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

as described in http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can use escape charaters...

```
LIKE '%100^%%' ESCAPE '^'
```

http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash to escape:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where ColName LIKE '%100\%%';
```

You may need to try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where ColName LIKE '%100\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```